# how can i get products for specific category from woocommerce restapi using php

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I tried doing the following and applying filter etc. seems like i am doing something wrong.Don't know what.

```
$data=$client->products->get('',array('category'=>33));
```

Comment: No one is helping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i tried if myself for about an hour and so it worked with this.

```
$data=$client->products->get('',array( 'filter[category]' => 'mens-fashion' ));
```